# Is there a way that I can scan comma values in Java?

Tags: java, variables, java.util.scanner

As I was trying to create a certain calculator function for my electrical engineering lessons,
I came upon a problem, that didn't let me scan comma values for the calculation.
Is there any way that i can solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Main {
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double voltage, resistance, current;
   
    System.out.println("Input value of R: ");
    resistance = scan.newDouble();

    System.out.println("Input value of I: ");
    current = scan.nextDouble();

    voltage = resistance * current;
  }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't allow it? Chance is, however, that the decimal point is .

Comment: Can you just input them with a dot instead of a comma?